# Do I need to use a physical security key if already use Passkeys?

Tags: 2fa, passkey

If I use Passkeys, do I need to enable 2fa and mfa or a physical security key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you don't *need* to.

Passkeys are [FIDO credentials](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/), the way you unlock your Passkey is up to the platform managing your Passkeys, eg. if your passkeys are managed by Google Password Manager on your Android phone, it will prompt for the method you would like to authenticate: it can be a hardware key like a Yubikey, or it can be your fingerprint, or any biometrics. On Apple phones it usually is the Face ID (and probably only that).

2FA (2-Factor Authentication) and MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication) are both ways that service providers use to enforce multiple authentication steps, they can also be completely unrelated to FIDO2 and Passkeys (eg. first step username & password, second step QR Code or magic link). A service provider could also enforce a security key / biometrics authentication (it *can* be a passkey authentication) as the *only* step to login (but I haven't seen many so far).

Hope I have clarified your question a little bit.